# Can't change css of all checkboxes when clicked on main checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

hello Guys,

I am trying to change to background and color of all my checkboxes withing a form with jQuery.
I can't get it to work.

This is what my code looks like now:
The HTML part:

```
<form action="" method="">
    <div id="child1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all-checkboxes" name="select-all-checkboxes" />
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs[]" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The jQuery part

```
$('form input.select-all-checkboxes:checkbox').live('click', function()
{
    if($(this).attr('checked') == true)
    {
        $(this).parent('form').children('input:checkbox').css({
            background: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
            border: '1px solid green'
        });   
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent('form').children('input:checkbox').css({
            background: 'none',
            border: '1px solid transparent'
        });   
    }
});
```

What it should do is that when you click on the checkbox with the class 'select-all-checkboxes', then all checkboxes within the form should get checked and get a different border and background.

I just don't get it to work. Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

Comment: You're trying to set the background and border of the actual `<input>` elements... I don't know if any browser allows this. http://jsfiddle.net/AyZA8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.  You need to use `parents` and `find`.  even so, the style rule seems to have no effect on the checkboxes in chrome

```
$(this).parents('form').find('input:checkbox')
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent is not the immediate ancestor of the inputs. You probably want to change the call to children() to a call to find().

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="">
<div id="child1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-all-checkboxes" name="select-all-checkboxes" />
</div>
<div id="child2">
    <input type="checkbox" class= 'child_box' name="checkboxs[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" class= 'child_box' name="checkboxs[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" class= 'child_box' name="checkboxs[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" class= 'child_box' name="checkboxs[]" />
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
 .greenbox{outline:#00ff00 solid 2px;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('.select-all-checkboxes').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.child_box').attr('checked', this.checked);
    if (this.checked == true){
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.child_box').addClass('greenbox');   
    }else{
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.child_box').removeClass('greenbox');  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that outline will show differently in IE and FF. border does not work in FF for checkboxes and I'm not sure how to set background for checkbox, but that's a CSS issue, not a js issue.

Comment: Yeah, I know. :) I tried something that looked like this, but that was not the way I wanted to do it. :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

$('.select-all-checkboxes').click(function() {

?